# Data compression within Internal Tables in SQL server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, compression

We are doing downgrade from enterprise to standard for couple of servers which are not using any enterprise features:

For one of our TFS(Team foundation server) database TFS_resx, when we ran

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

it returns null value for each column specifying that this database is not using any of enterprise features:

However, when we run the query as shown below to find at object level for any kind of compression used, we found one for internal table:

```
select so.name,so.type,so.type_desc,
sp.data_compression,sp.data_compression_desc 
from sys.partitions sp 
inner join sys.objects so 
on (so.object_id=sp.object_id) 
where sp.data_compression!=0
```

it says row compression is being used for an internal table

[image]

So, i would like to know how come this is not captured as an enterprise feature when i ran `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features`. Or may be it is not one.

Just curious in case anyone has witnessed if we need to remove this row compression from internal table of the DB in question or we would be good to downgrade (restore the tfs db onto standard version).

Thanks!

Comment: There is a simple way for you to test: take a backup and try to restore it on Standard.

Comment: This is normal if you have enterprise edition. This would not affect downgrade, I mean when you restore the DB from enterprise to standard

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Thats probably the best way, but we have standard for production servers, and to request for a set up in dev or test would require a process (flow of email for approval) that would take some time. So was wondering if it will be a success or would need to roll back.

Comment: If you have standard in production then you should have standard in dev and test. Period. If that takes time to set up, ok, that takes time to set up. Anything less is irresponsible IMHO.